# Custom php ini files for IIS7

Tags: iis-7.5, php5, php.ini, configuration

I have a Windows 2008 Web edition server setup with IIS7.5 and PHP 5.4.6 FastCGI installed. I would like to make use of the user INI files as described here:

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

I have PHP installed at `C:\PHP` and the main ini file is at `C:\PHP\php.ini`. The websites are in `C:\HostingSpaces\WebsiteName\wwwroot`, where I create the `.user.ini` file in the wwwroot directory.

The user file is never loaded, what could the problem be? `user_ini.filename` is set correctly to `.user.ini` as phpinfo shows.

Answer (score 1):

Updating PHP from 5.4.6 to 5.4.8 has fixed the issue, the .user.ini files are now picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Create `.user.ini` in `C:\HostingSpaces\WebsiteName\` directory not in `wwwroot` directory